# route command to add "link#X" as gateway?

Tags: networking, routing

i am not very experienced with networks and routes, but i am currently in a vpn that automagically configures some routes, but not the route i need.

The configured routes are like (it is a OS X)

```
10.16/16           link#9             USc             0        0    xxx0
```

and i am trying to add an identical one but changing the network. The problem is i can not add  "link#9" as gateway, i don't know how. I'm not sure if this will give me access to the resource i need, but at least i want to learn howto do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to don't set link#9, but IP address on the servers's side of VPN link. I think, that link#9 will add you operation system according of IP of this gateway.